# UICollectionView - remove all / clean table

Tags: ios

I have one list of cells(UIView) for use in a UIVIewControll. The UIVIewControll, reads in rows for the CollectionView, from the list depending on a value.

I then have two UICollectionViews showing different cells from the same list of UIViews.

A list oa arrays 1,2,3... is arrays:

-1-
-3-
-2-
-2-
-2-
-1-

//# Event: open
CollectionView_ONE then shows all from the list having value 1.
//# Event: open
CollectionView_TWO then shows all from the list having value 2.
//# Event: open
CollectionView_ONE then shows all from the list having value 3.

The problem is that, I can see the old values from the previous show in example CollectionView_ONE. I do call `reloadData`

Is there any way to clean items in a UICollectionView/UITableView withoug deleting the datasource.

Comment: That is actually what I already have, but I am reusing UICollectionView for the different arrays.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to click on one of the cells, and once you do, have the collection view display cells that are similar to that one?
I.E if you click on a cell with 1, only cells containing 1 are shown?

Comment: Yes, that is correct - but I am using two CollectionViews as I am animating between the two, when there is a change of data source.

Comment: Oh. Why not use a predicate search to filter your original area. Store your results in a new array and specify that array as the datasource. Should solve your problem. 
Once you want to filter back to the original array you can just specify it as the new datasource and then re-initialize your search array once a new click has been made.

Answer (score 2):

Why not make a new empty array and specify it as the datasource, this way you'd maintain your previous datasource array as well.